# How do I get a count of documents (records) for each mapping type in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, count, command-line-interface, aggregate

I have an ElasticSearch index called "myindex" that I load documents into for three different mapping types (person, event, and vendor)...

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/person/_bulk --data-binary  @../JSON_DATA/persons.json
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/event/_bulk --data-binary  @../JSON_DATA/events.json
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/vendor/_bulk --data-binary  @../JSON_DATA/vendors.json
```

I can see that the index was created successfully by using the command:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

I can successfully list all mapping types by using the command:

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping/?pretty'
```

**MY QUESTION - PART A:** How do I get an aggregated/total count of documents **for each and every** mapping type in an explicitly named index ("myindex")?  In other words, I'd like to know the number of documents for each and every mapping type.

NOTE: I tried `curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_count/?pretty'` but it only returns the total count, across all mapping types, not by each mapping type.  In other words, it did not break down the county beach mapping type.

**MY QUESTION - PART B:** Given being able to get an aggregate/total count of documents for each mapping type, how do I get an aggregated count for any one specific mapping type stored in an explicitly named index ("myindex")?  In other words, I'd like to know the number of documents for one explicitly named mapping type (e.g. "event") under the index "myindex".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Elastic search are you using?

Under 2.x , your queries should work just as fine , all you need to add is the document type in your query so you can get an specific count per type.

For example , take a look at this full example :

```
DELETE testindex
PUT testindex
PUT testindex/_mapping/users
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "standard"
    }
  }
}

PUT testindex/_mapping/users2
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "standard"
    }
  }
}

PUT testindex/users/1
{
  "name" : "Albert"
}

PUT testindex/user2/1
{
  "name" : "Albert"
}

GET testindex/_count 

{
  "count": 2,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  }
}

GET testindex/users/_count 

{
  "count": 1,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  }
}



GET testindex/users2/_count 

{
  "count": 1,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

To correct my comment based on @IanGabes comment and answer to part B , this is how you get the count per mapping :

```
GET /testindex/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "countPerMapping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that **size 0** is to avoid showing you results in the query and focus only in the aggregation. Where each bucket's key is the name of the mapping and doc_count the number of documents.

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "countPerMapping": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "user2",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "users",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or using curl

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/testindex/_search" -d'
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "countPerMapping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Hi Yeikel.  You answered the second part of my question (Part B) but did not answer the first (Part A).  I want to run one single command that returns the document count for each Mapping Type (in your example that would be "users" and "users2"), at the same time... with a count breakdown for each.

Comment: @InformationTechnology I am afraid that there is no such option. As far as I know , all you can is to get a count of all or to write custom code to do so

Comment: @InformationTechnology Piggy backing on @Yeikel's answer, you can run an aggregation on the `_type` field in a given index, to get a count. `GET /{index_name}/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "countPerMapping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type",
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @IanGabes Tried to run it using "curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search { "aggs": { "countPerMapping": { "terms": { "field": "_type", "size": 20 } } } }'" and it didn't work.

Comment: @InformationTechnology Please take a look at the updated answer. We have to thank IanGabes for his help as I did not know about this possibility as well.

Comment: I just tested and it works.  Thank you to both of you (Yeikel and IanGabes).